# Can't find the channel using tdlib with gogram

Tags: go, telegram

I'm using github.com/amarnathcjd/gogram/telegram to get channel messages, I've installed the tdlib build and I'm using this code:

```
func main() {
    client, err := telegram.NewClient(telegram.ClientConfig{
        AppID: appID, AppHash: appHash,
    })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    client.Login(phone)

    tgchannel, err := client.GetChannel(channelIDint)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    client.Idle() 
}
```

Login is fine. But when I try to get the channel I get this error message:
no channel with id -10020055**** or missing from cache

I've tried to add a Join before, just in case:

```
    err = client.JoinChannel(channelIDint)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
```

but I get a similar error message:
there is no peer with id 112094*** or missing from cache
This id seems to omit the first three number and the minus (-100) of the channel id, don't know why.

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Telegram, channel IDs are typically represented in the format -100xxxxxxxxxx, where xxxxxxxxxx is the actual channel ID. However, [based on this issue](https://github.com/AmarnathCJD/gogram/issues/14#issuecomment-1383105059), it appears that the gogram library expects the channel ID to be provided as an integer without the -100 prefix.

I dunno where u got the channelIDint but something like this piece of could should works:

```
func main() {
    client, err := telegram.NewClient(telegram.ClientConfig{
        AppID: appID, AppHash: appHash,
    })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    client.Login(phone)

    // remove the "-100" prefix from the channel ID
    channelIDint := 2005512345 // your actual channel ID without the "-100" prefix

    tgchannel, err := client.GetChannelFull(channelIDint)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    // print the channel information
    fmt.Println(tgchannel.Title)
    fmt.Println(tgchannel.Description)

    client.Idle()
}
```